# How to Generate GraphClient using the Microsoft Graph SDK using Username and password?

Tags: azure, microsoft-graph-api, microsoft-graph-sdks

How can i generate a graph client using the username and password using Microsoft Graph SDK?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

You can create a GraphServiceClient object as shown below if you want to pass user name.

```
IPublicClientApplication publicClientApplication = PublicClientApplicationBuilder
            .Create(clientId)
            .WithTenantId(tenantID)
            .Build();

UsernamePasswordProvider authProvider = new UsernamePasswordProvider(publicClientApplication, scopes);

GraphServiceClient graphClient = new GraphServiceClient(authProvider);

User me = await graphClient.Me.Request()
                .WithUsernamePassword(email, password)
                .GetAsync();
```

Please refer to this [Username / Password Provider document](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/sdks/choose-authentication-providers?tabs=CS#usernamepassword-provider)

Please refer this to implement [Resource Owner Password Credential Flow](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory/develop/v2-oauth-ropc), this is not a recommended flow and it should be used only when there is no scope for other flows.

Comment: Hi, if the posted answer resolves your question please mark it as the answer by clicking the check mark. Doing so helps others find answers to their questions.

Comment: Hi, I tried the above solution and it gives me an error: Message: Insufficient privileges to complete the operation. Please let me know why is that?

Comment: If using UsernamePasswordProvider is not a recommended flow, could you please answer https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64602154/unable-to-send-email-via-microsoft-graph-api-with-delegated-permission/64603215#64603215