# Unable to send email via Microsoft Graph API with Delegated Permission

Tags: azure-active-directory, microsoft-graph-api

I created a C# console application to send email using Microsoft Graph API. On adding Mail.Send **Application** Permission, it works fine. But, because of company requirements, I was asked to use Mail.Send **Delegated** Permission instead and with that permission I don't see it working and I see this error:

[image]

Are there any steps I should consider doing after adding Mail.Send **Delegated** Permission in order to get this working?

[image]

Here is my code:

```
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        // Azure AD APP
        string clientId = "<client Key Here>";
        string tenantID = "<tenant key here>";
        string clientSecret = "<client secret here>";

        Task<GraphServiceClient> callTask = Task.Run(() => SendEmail(clientId, tenantID, clientSecret));
        // Wait for it to finish
        callTask.Wait();
        // Get the result
        var astr = callTask;
    }

    public static async Task<GraphServiceClient> SendEmail(string clientId, string tenantID, string clientSecret)
    {

        var confidentialClientApplication = ConfidentialClientApplicationBuilder
            .Create(clientId)
            .WithTenantId(tenantID)
            .WithClientSecret(clientSecret)
            .Build();

        var authProvider = new ClientCredentialProvider(confidentialClientApplication);       

        var graphClient = new GraphServiceClient(authProvider);

        var message = new Message
            {
                Subject = subject,
                Body = new ItemBody
                {
                    ContentType = BodyType.Text,
                    Content = content
                },
                ToRecipients = new List<Recipient>()
                {
                    new Recipient
                    {
                        EmailAddress = new EmailAddress { Address = recipientAddress }
                    }
                }
            };

         var saveToSentItems = true;

         await _graphClient.Users[<userprincipalname>]
                                .SendMail(message, saveToSentItems)
                                .Request()
                                .PostAsync();

        return graphClient;

    }
```

UPDATE:

Based on below answer, I updated code as follows:

```
var publicClientApplication = PublicClientApplicationBuilder
            .Create("<client-id>")
            .WithTenantId("<tenant-id>")
            .Build();

            var authProvider = new UsernamePasswordProvider(publicClientApplication);
```

```
var secureString = new NetworkCredential("", "<password>").SecurePassword;

User me = await graphClient.Me.Request()
                .WithUsernamePassword("<username>", secureString)
                .GetAsync();
```

I enabled "Allow public client flows" to fix an exception.

[image]

And now I see another exception: Insufficient privileges to complete the operation.

What am I missing?

UPDATE: Currently I see this exception with no changes in the code:

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The code you provided shows you use [client credential flow](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/sdks/choose-authentication-providers?view=graph-rest-1.0&tabs=CS#ClientCredentialsProvider) to do the authentication. When you use `Mail.Send` Application permission, use client credential flow is ok. But if you use `Mail.Send` Delegated permission, we can not use client credential. You should use [username/password flow](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/sdks/choose-authentication-providers?view=graph-rest-1.0&tabs=CS#UsernamePasswordProvider) to do authentication.

=================================**Update**===================================

Below is my code:

```
using Microsoft.Graph;
using Microsoft.Graph.Auth;
using Microsoft.Identity.Client;
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Security;

namespace ConsoleApp34
{
    class Program
    {
        static async System.Threading.Tasks.Task Main(string[] args)
        {
            Console.WriteLine("Hello World!");

            var publicClientApplication = PublicClientApplicationBuilder
            .Create("client id")
            .WithTenantId("tenant id")
            .Build();

            string[] scopes = new string[] { "mail.send" };

            UsernamePasswordProvider authProvider = new UsernamePasswordProvider(publicClientApplication, scopes);

            GraphServiceClient graphClient = new GraphServiceClient(authProvider);

            var message = new Message
            {
                Subject = "Meet for lunch?",
                Body = new ItemBody
                {
                    ContentType = BodyType.Text,
                    Content = "The new cafeteria is open."
                },
                ToRecipients = new List<Recipient>()
                {
                    new Recipient
                    {
                        EmailAddress = new EmailAddress
                        {
                            Address = "to email address"
                        }
                    }
                }
            };

            var securePassword = new SecureString();
            foreach (char c in "your password")
                securePassword.AppendChar(c);

            var saveToSentItems = true;

            await graphClient.Me
                    .SendMail(message, saveToSentItems)
                    .Request().WithUsernamePassword("your email", securePassword)
                    .PostAsync();
        }
    }
}
```

The reason for your error message `Insufficient privileges to complete the operation` is you use the code:

```
User me = await graphClient.Me.Request()
                .WithUsernamePassword("<username>", secureString)
                .GetAsync();
```

This code is used to get the user(me)'s information but not send email, you haven't added the permission to the app. So it will show `Insufficient privileges to complete the operation`. Please remove this code and use the code block in my code instead:

```
await graphClient.Me.SendMail(message, saveToSentItems)
                    .Request().WithUsernamePassword("your email", securePassword)
                    .PostAsync();
```

==============================**Update2**====================================

[image]

[image]

Comment: Thank you! I updated code as you suggested but I see an exception. Please see my updated question.

Comment: Hi @user989988 Please refer to the "Update" in my answer.

Comment: Thank you. I will try your code. Quick question - is it possible to send mail using delegated permissions without providing user password in the code? Please let me know.

Comment: @user989988 I'm afraid not. If you use delegated permissions, you have to provide password whatever flow you use(username/password flow, auth code flow....).

Comment: Thanks! Does this user need to have any licenses in order to use as sender address?

Comment: Also, do I have to enable "Allow public client flows" to get this working?

Comment: Hi @user989988 The user need to have o365 license, then he can send email. You'd better enable "Allow public client flows" because if you disable this button, you may need to provide secret when do authentication. But it seems `PublicClientApplicationBuilder` doesn't have a method to include the secret.

Comment: I see an exception happening with this code now (see attached image in the question). Could you please let me know what I am missing?

Comment: Hi @user989988 Did you use same code which I provided in my answer ? And which line does the error originate from ?

Comment: Yes I am using the same code you provided. This is the exception: Microsoft.Identity.Client: Federated service at https://msft.sts.microsoft.com/adfs/services/trust/2005/usernamemixed returned error: ID3242: The security token could not be authenticated or authorized.

Comment: @user989988 Could you please check the error occurs in which line of code ?

Comment: The error occurs after hitting the breakpoint in this line: await graphClient.Me
                    .SendMail(message, saveToSentItems)
                    .Request().WithUsernamePassword(_senderAddress, securePassword)
                    .PostAsync();

Comment: @user989988 Sorry, I can't reproduce your error message in my side. It works fine in my side and even though I made a lot of changes, it doesn't show same error message as yours.

Comment: thank you for letting me know - quick question: all I need in the application is Mail.Send delegated permission with 'allow public client flows' enabled right? Am I missing something?

Comment: @user989988 I provided two screenshots of my registered app under "Update2" in my answer for your reference.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/227928/discussion-between-user989988-and-hury-shen).

Comment: Hi I was trying to use this approach, here is the issue I posted https://stackoverflow.com/questions/77964573/facing-issue-with-ms-graph-send-email-through-delegated-permission-and-service-a?noredirect=1#comment137452507_77964573 .  Error: The given key 'Microsoft.Graph.AuthenticationHandlerOption' was not present in the dictionary.